# How to use Hilbert series to count combinatorial objects?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

In [THE SLOPES DETERMINED BY n POINTS IN THE PLANE](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0302106.pdf) by JEREMY L. MARTIN, Page 2, Theorem 1.1, a Hilbert series is used to compute some combinatorial objects:

Let $R_n=k[m_{1,2}, \ldots, m_{n-1,n}]$, and let $I_n$ be the ideal generated by
the tree polynomials of all rigidity circuits in the complete graph $K_n$. Then the coefficient $h(n,k)$ of the numerator of the Hilbert series of $R_n/I_n$ counts the number of perfect matchings on $[1, 2n − 4]$ with
exactly $k$ long pairs, that is, pairs not of the form $\{i,i + 1\}$.

In general, if we want to compute some combinatorial objects using Hilbert series, how to define the ring $R_n$ and the ideal $I_n$?

Are there some other examples which count some combinatorial objects using Hilbert series?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 7):

For a simplicial complex $\Delta$, the numerator of the Hilbert series of the Stanley-Reisner ring $k[\Delta]$ is precisely the $h$-polynomial of the simplicial complex. (Recall that the $h$-polynomial is, modulo proper indexing, obtained from the $f$-polynomial by plugging in $x-1$. The $f$-polynomial is the polynomial whose coefficients record the number of faces of $\Delta$ of each dimension.)

Often for nice simplicial complexes these $h$-polynomial coefficients have a combinatorial meaning. For instance, if $\Delta$ is the dual polytope to the regular (Type A) permutohedron, then the $h$-polynomial coefficients are the famous Eulerian numbers, which count permutations by descents: see https://oeis.org/A008292.

I don't think this is an instance where a Hilbert series "helps you count a 
class of combinatorial objects" per se, but it is a representative example of how the numerators of Hilbert series arise in algebraic combinatorics. In particular, I think the philosophy is that $h$-polynomials tend to behave like Eulerian polynomials; see for example the behavior for generalized permutohedra as worked out by Postnikov-Reiner-Williams (https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0609184) or check out the recent textbook by Petersen (https://www.springer.com/us/book/9781493930906).

Note that plugging in $1$ to the $h$-polynomial should give you the number of facets of $\Delta$, so if the coefficients of this polynomial are all nonnegative integers you should think that the coefficients count facets by some statistic (in the permutohedron case we get permutations <-> vertices of permutohedron <-> facets of the dual polytope, and the relevant statistic for permutations is descents). As Martin explains in his paper, in the case where $\Delta$ is shellable, there is always a choice of this statistic coming from a given shelling.

Comment: However, I will say the example you give fits in with my answer here: I would contend that Martin is not "using Hilbert series to count combinatorial objects" but rather that he is giving a combinatorial interpretation for the $h$-vector of a certain shellable simplicial complex.

Comment: In other words, I think the flow of information is backwards to how you presented it: the class of combinatorial objects tells us about the coefficients of the numerator of the Hilbert series, not the other way around.

Answer (score 2):

See:

[Mordechai Katzman, *Counting monomials*](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0504113v1)

> This paper presents two enumeration techniques based on Hilbert functions. The paper illustrates these techniques by solving two chessboard problems.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the Hilbert series is just a special case of the Frobenius map of an $S_n$-action on a (graded) vector space. Thus, any time you have a combinatorial statement about Schur positivity (thus arising from some representation of an $S_n$-module), where the coefficients are of combinatorial nature, you also have a Hilbert-series with a combinatorial interpretation.

Take for example, the graded vector space $C[x_1,\dotsc,x_n]$,
that comes with a natural $S_n$ action (permuting variables).
Then the (graded) Frobenius series is just $F=\sum_{\lambda \vdash n} s_{\lambda}(1,q,q^2,\dotsc)s_\lambda$
and the Hilbert series is $(1-q)^{-n}$, which can be obtained by taking the 
inner product $\langle F, h_{1^n} \rangle$ (the Hall inner product).

There are more examples in Jim Haglund's book, related to diagonal harmonics.

<s>For example, the Stanley symmetric functions are Schur positive, and the expansion is given by the Edelman-Green correspondence. At the same time, these are the [Frobenius image of certain generalized Specht modules](https://www.math.upenn.edu/~peal/polynomials/stanleySymmetric.htm#stanleySymFrobenius), so you can then quite easily give a combinatorial interpretation of the Hilbert series.</s>

Comment: I don’t understand in what sense we can get a Hilbert series without a grading somewhere.

Comment: Ah, yes, my bad. You need a graded Frobenius series... Otherwise it is a bit boring. So, say, take the modified Macdonald polynomials...